# Statsmodel SARIMAX Fitted values ('seasonally adjusted') look like they are one period ahead of the true data

Tags: python, statsmodels, arima

I am having some trouble using Statmodel's SARIMAX function to do seasonal adjustments for a data series I have. The code is below but generally my process is that I am testing a variety of SARIMA parameters on my data, picking the one with the lowest AIC, running the model, and then getting the fitted values. The issue is that for some datasets the fitted values (seasonally adjusted) basically just look like my original data shifted backwards from one period. Is there anything I am doing glaringly wrong here?

```
def seasonal_fit(data_to_fit, column_name):
    # finding sarima parameters
    p = d = q = range(0, 2)
    pdq = list(itertools.product(p, d, q))
    seasonal_pdq = [(x[0], x[1], x[2], 12)
                    for x in list(itertools.product(p, d, q))]

    param_dict = []
    keys = ['Parameters', 'Seasonal Parameters', 'AIC']

    for param in pdq:
        for param_seasonal in seasonal_pdq:
            try:
                mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(data_to_fit, order=param,
                                                seasonal_order=param_seasonal, enforce_stationarity=False, enforce_invertibility=False)
                # , enforce_stationarity=False, enforce_invertibility=False)
                results = mod.fit()
                insert = [param, param_seasonal, results.aic]
                param_dict.append(dict(zip(keys, insert)))
            except:
                continue
    param_dict = pd.DataFrame(param_dict)
    best_fit = param_dict.loc[param_dict['AIC'].idxmin()]

    mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(data_to_fit,
                                    order=(
                                        best_fit['Parameters'][0], best_fit['Parameters'][1], best_fit['Parameters'][2]),
                                    seasonal_order=(best_fit['Seasonal Parameters'][0], best_fit['Seasonal Parameters']
                                                    [1], best_fit['Seasonal Parameters'][2], best_fit['Seasonal Parameters'][3]), enforce_stationarity=False, enforce_invertibility=False)
    results = mod.fit()
    pdb.set_trace()
    fitted_values = pd.DataFrame(results.fittedvalues)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone stumbles upon this I found the answer myself after a bit of searching. Here is one of the sources (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/330928/time-series-prediction-shifted). Basically -- ARIMA by its nature lags and uses priors to predict forward. You're necessarily going to see the curve shifted to the right by x periods, with x being the number of differences that occur. Lesson learned is don't be surprised when something weird happens when you try to implement something you don't fully understand...